# Executing Selenium Ruby tests via PSEXEC

Tags: selenium, batch-file, windows-10, internet-explorer-11, psexec

I am trying to execute a batch file via psexec.  The batch file is on another machine.
The batch file executes a Selenium test suite and it interacts with the IE Browser.

When I had executed it using PSExec on a Windows 7 machine, the tests executed without any problems.

Now the remote machine has been upgraded to Windows 10.  I am getting errors that the Selenium suite is unable to locate the IE browser window.  The test is using IE 11.

Is there something I need to do in my configurations on the Windows 10 box so that it can find the IE browser when the tests are executed via PSExec ?

Below is the PSExec command that I am using:

```
c:\Sysinternals\PsExec.exe \\REMOTESERVER -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD  BATCHFILE.bat
```

Thank you

Comment: I would advise you to provide, at the very least, the content of `BATCHFILE.bat`, if you wish us to assist you with your issue. It is my experience that the default browser in Windows 10 is Edge, not IE, so make sure that you're specifically calling the correct browser in that code.

Comment: Can the batch file work well without PSExec on local machine on Windows 10? What is the exactly error message? Besides, the PSExec connection might be denied on Windows 10 in some reports. To fix this you will need to allow 2 ports – TCP/445 and UDP/137 or disable the remote Windows 10 firewall. For the detailed steps, you could refer to [this article](https://ozitpro.wordpress.com/2016/08/09/allowing-psexec-on-windows-10-pcs/).